# Is it normal to have two shadow files in /etc directory?

Tags: login, password-recovery

I am having an issue with logging in after an upgrade to 12.04. I have been using (unsuccessfully) [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-help/user-forgottenpassword.html) to reset the password.

In `/etc` I found two shadow files: `shadow` and `shadow-` . The files seem identical. Are there supposed to be two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/etc/shadow` is the file that will be used by the login system. `/etc/shadow-` is a backup file that is not used (except for backup purpose). The same applies to `/etc/group-` and `/etc/password-`. Older backup files can be found at `/var/backups/`.

Comment: Likewise for /etc/gshadow(-)